# What does this quote about "pasty-skinned programmers" mean?

Tags: phrases

> “Note to self: Pasty-skinned programmers ought not stand in the Mojave desert for multiple hours.” -John Carmack

("Pasty Skin" means not healthy and pale skin.)

What does this quote mean?

Comment: Um... it means exactly what it says. Those with pale skin should not stand in the desert sun. Perhaps it's a metaphor: is there more context?

Comment: It means a bit more than that. The "note to self" part implies that John Carmack himself *is* a pasty-skinned programmer who has stood in the Mojave desert for multiple hours.

Comment: @AndrewLeach You are right. I googled for the source of this quote and found if was from here http://www.bluesnews.com/cgi-bin/finger.pl?id=1&time=20000515035055. I was assuming the quote might have be directed to programmer. Since the context is around the time when launching rocket, it must be taken literally. Thank you.

Comment: @Talespin_Kit: You may not have fully understood the significance of "pasty-skinned". It doesn't really have any direct connection to "not healthy". It just means office-bound people who don't get out in the sun much, so they haven't built up a protective tan. Such people would blister and burn *very* quickly in the desert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this should be posted as an answer, considering the comments above. However, as we may all know, programmers usually spend most of their time seated in a room at a desk, thinking and coding, away from sun. Being strong in thinking and mind, they might not be the same in physical appearance, specially if they don't spend enough time doing exercises. This makes them less outdoor-tolerant!

Therefore if one happens to spend several hours in a desert, sun will damage their pale skin!

*P.S. This reminds me of a few scenes:*

1. *The Big Bang Theory: Sheldon joins Penny to do some exercise.*
2. *The Big Bang Theory: The folks are off the desert to take photos for a comicon and they get into trouble.*
3. *[White and Nerdy](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCQQyCkwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DN9qYF9DZPdw&ei=9k3jU6WpMLKO7QbloICwAQ&usg=AFQjCNGUGBqUPnfdzcgtsFuKABky7aU7gg&sig2=gvBbXFgdhF0sWakXZtZA6w&bvm=bv.72676100,d.ZGU) by Yankovich.*

Comment: The Daystar!  It burns!

Answer (score 3):

*Pasty-skinned programmers ought not stand in the Mojave desert for multiple hours*, on its own, is stating the obvious. **Note to self**, stating this obvious fact, means that John Carmack is laughing at himself for doing such a stupid thing. He's saying "what a fool I was!", and it's intended to be funny because it implies that even though his resultant suffering from sunburn impressed upon him the need for precautions in such circumstances, he needs to write himself a note if he is to remember this obvious fact in future.